# Jquery Onclick событие после того как вставил html('')

Tags: html, jquery

У меня есть сторонний скрипт, который вставляет календарь в контейнер

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Календарь поделен на блоки, у каждого блока есть класс. например:

```
<div class='event-120'></div>
```

А теперь собственно проблема, я пытаюсь отловить клик на этот класс, но у меня ничего не получается, я предполагаю, что это все из-за того, что календарь вставляется динамически, и в DOM дереве просто не появляется (если открыть код страницы, мы ничего не увидим, соответственно, кроме контейнера c id `calendar`, хотя при нажатии f12 в хроме, его html-код можно посмотреть), поэтому мой скрипт типа:

```
   $('.event-120').on('click',function(){
        alert('Show event 120');
    });
```

Ничего отловить не может. Есть ли какие-либо способы отлавливать события, которые вставляются таким вот образом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#calendar').on('click', 'div[class^="event-"]', function() {
    eventLink = $(this).data('url');
    alert(eventLink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar">
  <div class="event-120" data-url="/page?id=120">контент 120</div>
  <div class="event-121" data-url="/page?id=121">контент 121</div>
  <div class="event-122" data-url="/page?id=122">контент 122</div>
  <div class="event-123" data-url="/page?id=123">контент 123</div>
</div>
```

Можно и подругому

```js
$('#calendar').on('click', 'div[class^="event-"]', function() {
    eventClass = $(this).attr('class');
    eventClass = eventClass.split('-');
    alert('/page.php?id='+eventClass[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar">
  <div class="event-120">контент 120</div>
  <div class="event-121">контент 121</div>
  <div class="event-122">контент 122</div>
  <div class="event-123">контент 123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а не ответите на вопрос, как теперь грамотно подгружать в него события вида [event-XX] [link_url]. Я просто думаю что нужно завести массив двумерный. И обернуть $('#calendar').on('click','.event-120',function() в цикл. И в цикле подставлять. Это будет правильно ?

Comment: не понимаю. давайте словами

Comment: Просто в календаре много эвентов и у каждого эвента будет своя ссылка. Вот я и хочу чтобы при клике на эвент срабатывал onklick который будет редиректить на страницу события. Можно обрабатывать нажатие по любому классу с началом event-??, и завести массив с ключом по 'event-120'=>'link_url_120'   после чего засунуть в тело функции которое вы привели выше засунуть цикл и перебирать массив ища  нужную ссылку по ключу события, но как получить сам текст  event-120 в переменную?

Comment: меня интересует правильный путь реализации

Comment: сделал апдейт на свой ответ

Comment: И еще один вариант

Comment: большое спасибо особенно за второй вариант )

Comment: Тогда ответ можно пометить как правильный )

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста что делать если у меня это выглядит вот так. <a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end event-120" style="border-color: rgb(214, 187, 34); top: 649px; bottom: -949px; z-index: 1; left: 0%; right: 0%; background-color: rgb(214, 187, 34);">Birthday</a>. Конструкция вида a[class^="event-"]  не работает

Comment: `^` заменить на `*`